# Limit Salesforce1 user to a single tab?

Tags: salesforce1-app

Is it possible to set up a user in Salesforce1 so that they only have access to a single tab?  (which would be a custom VF or Lightning page).

We are considering trying to use SF1 for a kiosk-like application, and would like to make sure that users at the kiosk couldn't navigate to another tab.  I assume we can't hide the gray tabs on the bottom (Help, Log Out, etc.) but are there any other tabs (Feed, etc.) that can't be hidden?   I know object tabs are controlled via profile access.

And what about the search in the sidebar?  Can that be hidden?

I assume there's no way to lock the sidebar in a hidden state..

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

```
1) First go to Create/Tabs in Setup and choose 'Visualforce Tabs' to create your tab that will activate a VF page.
2) Do a search for 'Salesforce1 Navigation' and remove all tabs on the right side and just add your VF tab that you created in #1.
```

As far as the side bar. If you have a technical person that can help you, you can try a CSS workaround. [Check out ways to hide the side bar](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008m2oIAA)

Comment: Thanks, but won't your #2 remove those tabs for all users?  I want to only remove them for a particular user/profile.

Comment: And your link is about the sidebar in customer portal, not SF1..